# NextJS Dynamic Routing issue

Tags: reactjs, hyperlink, next.js

I get this Error creating blog in NextJS.  Error: Multiple children were passed to  with `href` of `/` but only one child is supported

What am i doing wrong here ?

===============================
Server Error
Error: Multiple children were passed to  with `href` of `/` but only one child is supported https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/link-multiple-children

## This error happened while generating the page. Any console logs will be displayed in the terminal window.

```
<nav className={styles.main-nav}>
      <ul>
        <Link href='/'> <li>Home</li></Link>
        <Link href='/about'> <li>About</li></Link>
        <Link href='/blog'> <li>Blog</li></Link>
        <Link href='/contact'> <li>Contact</li></Link>
        </ul>
      </nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside 'Link' component must be 'a' tag

```
<ul>
       <li> <Link href='/'> <a>Home</a> </Link> </li>
       <li> <Link href='/about'> <a>About</a> </Link> </li>
       <li> <Link href='/blog'> <a>Blog</a> </Link> </li>
       <li> <Link href='/contact'> <a>Contact</a> </Link> </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you Volodymyr Zelenyi. I fixed the issue.